# Command arguments autocompletion in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I try to see the arguments available for the commands as a **root user**, I see only the directories:

.# apt

```
.adobe/                          id_rsa                           .ssh/
.bash_history                    .local/
```

But when as a **normal user** I do this, I get the list of arguments:

.$ apt

```
autoclean     clean         edit-sources  list          rdepends      showsrc       
autoremove    depends       full-upgrade  moo           remove        source.
```

Someone please explain the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should try what is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103655/autocompletion-doesnt-work-while-logged-as-root)

> Check your /root/.bashrc file for these lines
>
> ```
> if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
>   . /etc/bash_completion
> fi
> ```
>
> If they do not exist add them to the end of the file using your
>   favorite text editor.